# Angularjs ng-model-options is not working.

Tags: angularjs

I have a pattern on my controller

```
 $scope.pattern = {
    name: /[a-zA-Z]{5,}/
 }
```

On the view

```
<input type="text" name="name" data-ng-model="name" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"  ng-pattern="pattern.name" required />
      <div ng-show="contactForm.name.$dirty && contactForm.name.$invalid">
        <span ng-show="contactForm.name.$error.required">The name field is mandatory</span>
        <span ng-show="contactForm.name.$error.pattern">The name must be at least 5 characters long</span>
      </div>
```

I want the field to be validate only when it looses the focus but it doesn't it validates every time I press a button.

Comment: You forgot the fiddle :)

Comment: Are you using AngularJS 1.3.x? It's still in beta right now, but this is only supported in 1.3.x.

Answer (score 17):

`ngModelOptions` was introduced only in Angular 1.3.x

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

If you want to use similar functionality in Angular 1.2.x, check out this poly fill:

https://github.com/fergaldoyle/modelOptions

Comment: Nice answer. I was using Angular 1.2.x and the module just works fine.

Comment: Rather just upgrade to Angular 1.3 if you want to use it's features instead of making an old version work with polyfills. The IE8 support drop shouldn't be an issue if you have reasonable clients ;-)

Comment: What if you have a massive application developed and tested with 1.2, and you just want to easily add a denounce to an input. Instead of upgrading / refactoring the entire app to work with 1.3, you could easily drop in a module like this.  

Or for corporate environments where IE8 is widely used. If you think as a developer you can dictate to IT departments or your clients what browser they should use I don't think you are living in the real world.